# Reuse vuelidate validation in VueJS template

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using `vuelidate` to validate forms in my VueJS app. Here is a sample validation rule:

```
validations() {
    const validationRules = {
        myValidationRule: {
        required: requiredIf(
            vm => vm.someProperty && vm.anotherProperty !== "COUNTRY"
        )}
    }
}
```

The PUG template used in the component:

```
template(v-if="someProperty === false || anotherProperty === 'COUNTRY'")
```

As you can see the `v-if` attribute contains a condition *similar* to `myValidationRule`.

Is it possible to "reuse" the validation rule `myValidationRule` in `v-if`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$v` object of vuelidate in your PUG template. For more information refer [this](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-v-values).

Eg. `$v.myValidationRule.required`